# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end under ?>

Tags: php, html, sql, syntax

I am trying to get this php code to run and I am getting an error that says "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/TestSite1/betting.php on line 54", I checked multiple times that I closed all of the brackets, quotations, and semicolons. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
       Person: <select name="person">
    <option value="Karl">Karl</option>
    <option value="Erik">Erik</option>
    <option value="Patrick">Patrick</option>
    </select>
       Money: <input type="text" name="am"><br>
       Pass: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    $person=$_POST["pass"];
    $money=$_POST["am"];

       class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
      function __construct()
      {
        $this->open('betting.db');
      }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully<br>";
    }
    if ($passwd == '3nt3rpr1s3'){
      print "Correct Password<br>";
       $sql =<<<EOF
         UPDATE people set money = "$money" where person=$pname;
         EOF;
    } else {
      print "\nIncorrect Password!";
    }
    $ret = $db->exec($sql);
    if(!$ret){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }

       $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * from people;
    EOF;
    $ret = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
      echo "<br>ID = ". $row['id'] . "\n";
      echo "<br>Person = ". $row['person'] . "\n";
      echo "<br>Money = ". $row['money'] . "\n";
    }
    $db->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Generally means that you're missing a closing `}`; but could be the spaces before your `EOF;` at the end of your heredocs

Comment: Seems like all braces are accounted for @MarkBaker It must be the spaces before `EOF;` --- Least, that's what my IDE tells me.

Comment: Use a decent text editor or IDE that has syntax highlighting. It'll probably tell you instantly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `EOF;` contain spaces before it and are not allowed as per [`heredoc manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Reformatted:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
       Person: <select name="person">
    <option value="Karl">Karl</option>
    <option value="Erik">Erik</option>
    <option value="Patrick">Patrick</option>
    </select>
       Money: <input type="text" name="am"><br>
       Pass: <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
    $person=$_POST["pass"];
    $money=$_POST["am"];

       class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
      function __construct()
      {
        $this->open('betting.db');
      }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully<br>";
    }
    if ($passwd == '3nt3rpr1s3'){
      print "Correct Password<br>";
       $sql =<<<EOF
         UPDATE people set money = "$money" where person=$pname;
EOF;
    } else {
      print "\nIncorrect Password!";
    }
    $ret = $db->exec($sql);
    if(!$ret){
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }

       $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * from people;
EOF;
    $ret = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
      echo "<br>ID = ". $row['id'] . "\n";
      echo "<br>Person = ". $row['person'] . "\n";
      echo "<br>Money = ". $row['money'] . "\n";
    }
    $db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning from the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) man page

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system. This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. The closing delimiter must also be followed by a newline.
>
> If this rule is broken and the closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse error will result at the last line.